# Cookies are not being accessible in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angular-cookies

I am working on login application.

For that, I am calling a backend service which is a post call. It returns a cookie. Inside cookie, there is a token. I need that token.

I am trying to get that token, but it is coming null when I try to access in using $cookie.get method.

Can anyone suggest me what could be the possible reason?

Here is the code:

```
$http({
          url:"http://10.11.0.11:4440/j_security_check",
          method:"POST",
          data:data,
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
         }).then(function successCallback(response) {
           console.log("Login Success!!");
           console.log( "cookie ", response.headers('Set-Cookie') ); //Returning NULL
           console.log("cookies"+$cookies.get('JSESSIONID')); //Returning undefined
           $location.url("/report");
      }, function errorCallback() {
        $scope.loginError = "Invalid username/password combination.";
        $scope.result = 'error';
        console.log('Login failed');
      });
```

Here is the snap of response which I am getting in my browser's network tool:

[image]

Comment: The code shows a POST request but the network tool shows a GET request. Those are not the same transactions.

Comment: @georgeawg : Oh yes, Just now I too noticed. But I am passing it as a post request. I dont understand how it is showing GET